# How to know the size of a keyspace and column family in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Recently I've started working on Grails integration with Cassandra using the Java driver for cassandra(cassandra-driver-core-2.0.2).
So I was curious to know how we can find out how much size our table is taking to store the data in cassandra DB.

I have created a keyspace with name Customkeyspace and a column family called Movie in it.
So I was curious to know which tool/Command I have to use to know the size of the keyspace/Column family ?

Comment: Cassandra doesn't deal with tables but with `Column`s and `SuperColumn`s in a `KeySpace`. Also, These columns and SuperColumns can be clustered. Essentially, do you want to size the `KeySpace`?

Comment: Thanks for the information, Yes I am interested in Knowing the size of a Keyspace as well as the Column family.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get statistics regarding column families in Cassandra, you can simply run the command:

```
nodetool cfstats
```

It reports statistics about tables which include the live data size as well as on disk.

The documentation about this utility for Cassandra 2.1 is available [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html).

Comment: So I run this command(nodetool cfstats) in the nodetool.I got this information-Table: movie SSTable count: 0 Space used (live): 0 Space used (total): 0 Space used by snapshots (total): 0 SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.0 Memtable cell count: 1887 Memtable data size: 49225....So why the no of bytes taken  is showing in the Memtable data size ? Why the size is coming 0 in Space used(Live) and Space used(Total) ?..Furthermore if a user wants to know how much data size a row is taking in cassandra for a particular Column family ? how can we do that ?

Comment: I would suspect it's because when your ran `nodetool cfstats`, you have just created the table and haven't flushed your writes to disk yet.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a small script to print `nodetool` results in a nice table:

```
#!/bin/sh
nodetool cfstats -H | awk -F ' *: *' '
  BEGIN { print "Keyspace,Table,Live,Total" }
  /^Keyspace : / { ks = $2 }
  /\tTable:/ { t = $2 }
  /\tSpace used .live/ { sp = $2 }
  /\tSpace used .total/ { print ks "," t "," sp "," $2 }
' | column -s , -t
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved me a ton of time debugging my database!

Answer (score 2):

To get the statistics regarding column families in Cassandra with respect to keyspaces or tables, you can simply run the below command:

`nodetool cfstats`

**Result**: This will return the complete statistics related to available keyspaces.

But, in case you want to find out the statistics of specific keyspaces or tables, run below command:

**For Keyspace(s)** : 
`nodetool cfstats <keyspace_name>` OR
`nodetool cfstats -H <keyspace_name>`

**For Table(s)** : 
`nodetool tablestats <keyspace_name>.<table_name>` OR
`nodetool tablestats -H <keyspace_name>.<table_name>`

**Note:** -H denotes Human Readable format

For more details please refer, [nodetool cfstats](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html)

Findings:

1. You might see `SSTable count` as 0
2. `Space used (live)` and `Space used (total)` as 0 bytes

To know WHY(s) of the above two findings please refer: [Reason of why SSTable count shown as 0](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html)

Comment: @vikash-kumar-choudharyThe link showing the reason is broken. Can you please update?

Comment: Hi @Phuong Vu, For me, it's working. If you still face the issue, click on the given link to see the details: http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the command below based on old and new version of Cassandra.

**nodetool cfstats** or **nodetool tablestats**

Above command will give you size details about keyspace and table. Also you can refer below link to get more ddetails about how to use with different options 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsTablestats.html